# Why does ulrdispsvcfastwl wakelock keep draining my battery?

Tags: battery, nexus-5, google-play-services, wakelock

I am using Slimkat ROM on a Nexus 5 with At&t. My battery life has been excellent with this ROM. Recently I've been getting a ulrdispsvcfastwl wakelock that will keep the phone awake continuously for hours until it drains the battery. The wakelock is usually set by google play services. Does anyone know what this wakelock does and if it is safe to disable it?

Comment: The only info I could find is that this is managed by `UlrDispatchingService` but I'm not clear on what that is.  In any case I would think that it's safe to disable -- worst case, Play Services stops working and you have to re-enable it.  You could always do a Nandroid backup beforehand just in case.

Comment: This [XDA post](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=64087143&postcount=5312) says it is not safe to limit.  Elsewhere on the same thread you will find reference to  GPS breaking when limiting this

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this wakelock is related to google location history reporting. I found this wakelock shown up today only after I enabled the Google Location history. It could be equally true with Google Now location reporting.

Basically, to my understanding, this wakelock is related with reporting the location back to the servers which would help seeing the location history. I disabled the Google location history reporting and the wakelock is not active anymore.

I hope it helps.